# Usage of both EasyTracker and ActionBarSherlock on Android

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I would like to use both **EasyTracker** and **ActionBarSherlock** in my Android app. I was considering to rewrite the EasyTracker classes, those which extend the Activity and ListActivity classes, to extend the corresponding ActionBarSherlock classes, so that updates of the latter won't break anything.

I'm concerned about the performance of the app by doing so.
Does anyone know another way, i.e. more efficient, to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

With the forthcoming ActionBarSherlock version 4 you can create your own base activities that extend from whatever class you want. Simply copy the contents of `SherlockActivity` into a new class and change which class it extends. Then you can use this new class as your base activity.

This will allow easier interoperability with libraries that also require a base class for use.

Version 4 is due for an initial release on March 7th (hopefully). You can obtain it from the `4.0-wip` branch of [the repository](http://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) for now, but it will be released to `master` and developed in `dev` shortly.