# ActionBarSherlock 4 - extend from another class?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to use:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

with ActionBarSherlock 4 and I got stuck on the part where my MainActivity class extends SherlockActivity while the Pull-to-Refresh library extends ListActivity..

Anyone know what can I do?

I also saw another old post:
[Usage of both EasyTracker and ActionBarSherlock on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586401/usage-of-both-easytracker-and-actionbarsherlock-on-android)

That Jake says there that "you can create your own base activities that extend from whatever class you want"

How can I do that on my ListActivity?

Thanks in advanced,
Din...

Comment: `PullToRefreshListView` is a widget. It is not an activity, let alone one that extends `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock also contains a `SherlockListActivity` class, which provides the same functionality as `ListActivity`. One caveat is that `SherlockListActivity` does **not** extend `FragmentActivity`, so you will be unable to use `Fragment`s in that Activity as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837916/sherlocklistactivity-does-not-have-getsupportfragmentmanager-method).

If you'd like to use Fragments, ActionBarSherlock, and one of the helper classes to use `ListView`s, I would suggest using `SherlockActivity` and a `Fragment` that extends `SherlockListFragment`.